# set default value when calling select_month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am not able to figure how to set default month to 4 using select_month.  not sure what i did wrong.  thanks.

```
select_month(Date.today,  
             :field_name => 'month', 
         :use_month_numbers => true, 
         :html_options => { :selected => '4'})
```

Answer (score 5):

I think here you need to use Date.new(2011, 4) instead of Date.today to set a default

```
select_month(Date.new(2011, 4),  
             :field_name => 'month', 
             :use_month_numbers => true)
```

Comment: how can I modify to start from say: oct,2nd, 2017. Only post oct should be shown?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this in my credit card form by using:

```
select_month 6, { add_month_numbers: true }
```

That renders with June as the default. I use this for rendering the users selected month when the cc form is re-rendered. I do not actually hard code that 6.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this simply by using the current date, works great on my credit card form:

```
select_month Date.today.month, {add_month_numbers: true}
```